# Pycharm does not return my function to the console

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

My functions return variables but after "return" code does not show on console anything unlike Jupiter notebook.

```
dollar = 1.0
quarter = dollar / 4
dime = dollar / 10
nickel = dollar / 20
penny = dollar / 100


def quarter_returns(change):
    counter_quarter = 0
    while change >= quarter:
        change = change - quarter
        counter_quarter = counter_quarter + 1
    return "Your quarter change is {}, {}".format(counter_quarter,round(change,2))

quarter_returns(0.56)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that is not the [interactive mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode). Use [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to see the results:

```
print(quarter_returns(0.56))
```

Output:

```
Your quarter change is 2, 0.06
```

Comment: Don't wanna do that. I googled it but I do not saw anything

Comment: @CeylanBAĞCI Excuse me, what do you not want to do? Display the results? What is the problem then?

Comment: a func  should show string statements with return code on console. am I wrong

Comment: Don't think to get functionalities like Jupyter on terminal if you will try to run file using python command. Jupyter has been implemented in such a way that it automatically displays the value contained in variables. So it is on us whether we'll use print() in jupyter notebook or not. It is for saving the time of user. @Ayxan is correct as I see.